# How to find the cosine of the angle between the plane through $=(3,0,0), =(0,7,0)$, and $=(0,0,6)$ and the $$-plane?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm trying to find the cosine of the angle between the plane through  $=(3,0,0), =(0,7,0)$, and $=(0,0,6)$  and the  $$-plane, defined as the angle between their normal vectors.

[image]

Here's my attempt. First I find vectors:

$\vec{PQ} = \left\langle-3,7,0\right\rangle$

$\vec{PR} = \left\langle-3,0,6\right\rangle$

Then I find the cross product of the two above vectors to get the normal vector: \begin{pmatrix}42&18&21\end{pmatrix}

Then I calculate the magnitude of it:

$3\sqrt{281}$

$cos\left(\theta \right)=3\sqrt{281}$

Idk what to do now. This isn't right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two planes, so you need to calculate both normal vectors. In; this case you've only calculated the normal to the second $P_2$ in the diagram. Then you'll use that $a \cdot b = ||a|| ||b|| \cos \theta$ to get the angle between the two normals.

Comment: @CyclotomicField i got u, thanks homie makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your work so far, it is not correct to set $\cos(
\theta)$ equal to the magnitude of that vector you found.

---

You found a normal vector to that plane: $\langle 42,18,21\rangle\sim\langle 14,6,7\rangle$.

A normal vector to the other plane is $\langle1,0,0\rangle$.

So now find the cosine of the angle between these two vectors using the formula $\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{u}\rVert\lVert\vec{v}\rVert}$.

Comment: thanks brother, that makes sense

Comment: btw would it be technically wrong to simplify the vector cause if u use 14,6,7 to do the dot product it's no longer the same number yea?

Comment: The concept is you need _a_ normal vector to the plane. It does not matter which one. If you rescale, say by multiplying by $\frac13$, it still works. And it has no effect in the formula for $\cos\theta$ because each vector appears in the numerator _and_ the denominator. So any rescaling happens in both places, and the factors cancel out.

Comment: oh yea u right i forgot to scale the whole thing